# Python matrix input not working this way?

Tags: python, for-loop, matrix

I have tried several ways that are working. But, this one is not.
Please help me understand why ?

```py
row, col = 2, 3
mat1 = [[None]*col]*row
print(mat1)
for i in range(0, row):
    for j in range(0, col):
        mat1[i][j] = int(input())
print(mat1)
```

Input:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Expected:

```
[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
```

Getting:

```
[[4,5,6], [4,5,6]]
```

Comment: Probably a referential problem. Replace your mat1 initialization with a comprehension.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in line 2 when you create your matrix `mat1` with the `*` operator.

The two lots of `[[None]*col]` defined by `[[None]*3]*2` are referencing the same list in memory - this is why modifying your second list (unexpectedly) results in the first list being modified as well.

Another example:

```
>>> a = [[1, 2]*2]*3
>>> a
[[1, 2, 1, 2], [1, 2, 1, 2], [1, 2, 1, 2]]

>>> a[0][2] = 3
>>> a[0][3] = 4
>>> a
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

As you can see, changing `a[0]` led to the other two lists being changed as well.

As other answers have pointed out, this can be resolved with a list comprehension:

```
mat1 = [[None for _ in range(col)] for _ in range(row)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. I tested it on Google Colab:

```
row, col = 2, 3
mat1 = [[None for _ in range(col)] for _ in range(row)]
print(mat1)
for i in range(row):
    for j in range(col):
        mat1[i][j] = int(input())
print(mat1)
```

Comment: For me as well. Strage thing is both: >>>   mat1 = [[None for _ in range(col)] for _ in range(row)].  AND  >>>   mat1 = [[None]*col]*row   GIVES SAME RESULT. THEN why not ?

Comment: They are not the same; they just look the same. If you check the addresses of the two sub-Lists using id() it will confirm the comment made by @Portly1418

Comment: Or try `print(mat1[0] is mat1[1])`. That will be True with your original approach, but False with the solution in this answer.

Comment: As others have already commented, the reason `mat1 = [[None]*col]*row` gives the same initial print result as `mat1 = [[None for _ in range(col)] for _ in range(row)]` is because both create a 2x3 matrix filled with `None`. However, the difference is in their memory layout. The former creates rows that are references to the same list, so changing one row changes all rows. The latter creates independent rows, allowing individual row modification without affecting others.